# Refactoring: Replace Method with Method Object explanation

Tags: java, c#, coding-style, refactoring

I was looking for refactoring a too length method. Searching I found this technique:  [Replace Method with Method Object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceMethodWithMethodObject.html) but I don't understand at all.

If the method to refactor is:

```
public class Order {
  //Method to refactor
  public double price() {
    double primaryBasePrice;
    double secondaryBasePrice;
    double tertiaryBasePrice;

     //compute impl
  }

 //.....
}
```

With the web example the refactor *Replace Method with Method Object*  would be as next:

```
public class Order {

  //Method refactored
  public double price() {
    return new PriceCalculator(this).compute();
  }
  //.......
}

//Method object
public class PriceCalculator {
  private double primaryBasePrice;
  private double secondaryBasePrice;
  private double tertiaryBasePrice;

  public PriceCalculator(Order order) {
    //??
  }

  public double compute() {
    // impl
  }
}
```

But how `PriceCalculator` gets `primaryBasePrice`, `secondaryBasePrice`, `tertiaryBasePrice` values to do the compute?

I only see it is possible passing the values in the constructor as next:

```
//Method object
public class PriceCalculator {
  private double primaryBasePrice;
  private double secondaryBasePrice;
  private double tertiaryBasePrice;

  public PriceCalculator(Order order, double primaryBasePrice, 
     double secondaryBasePrice, double tertiaryBasePrice) {
    this.primaryBasePrice = primaryBasePrice;
    this.secondaryBasePrice = secondaryBasePrice;
    this.tertiaryBasePrice = tertiaryBasePrice;
  }

  public double compute() {
    // impl
  }
}
```

Otherwise, why pass in the constructor `order` instance reference? Why is needed?

- Passing instance of `order`:

  `return new PriceCalculator(this, primaryBasePrice, secondaryBasePrice, tertiaryBasePrice).compute();`
- Without `order` instance reference:

  `return new PriceCalculator(primaryBasePrice, secondaryBasePrice, tertiaryBasePrice).compute();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**But how PriceCalculator gets primaryBasePrice, secondaryBasePrice, tertiaryBasePrice values to do the compute?**

The same way it was before refactoring.

If you look at the original code, `primaryBasePrice`, `secondaryBasePrice` and `tertiaryBasePrice` are *local* variables, whose values are being set somewhere in the `//compute impl` section.

```
  public double price() {
    double primaryBasePrice;
    double secondaryBasePrice;
    double tertiaryBasePrice;

     // compute impl
     // all base price variables are assigned somewhere in here
  }
```

After refactoring, the `compute()` method has a copy of the `//compute impl` code, and simply assigns the exact same values to the fields in `PriceCalculator` as it did to the local variables before refactoring.

We need to pass in a reference to the `Order` object in case those values are dependent on its methods or internal state.

For instance, if we previously had

```
public double price() {
    double primaryBasePrice;
    double secondaryBasePrice;
    double tertiaryBasePrice;

    // some of compute impl
    primaryBasePrice = getPrimary();
    secondaryBasePrice = getSecondary();
    tertiaryBasePrice = getTertiary();
    // the rest of compute impl
}
```

after refactoring, we would instead have something like

```
public double compute() {
    double primaryBasePrice;
    double secondaryBasePrice;
    double tertiaryBasePrice;

    // some of compute impl
    primaryBasePrice = order.getPrimary();
    secondaryBasePrice = order.getSecondary();
    tertiaryBasePrice = order.getTertiary();
    // the rest of compute impl
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So to answer both your questions:

1. > But how PriceCalculator gets primaryBasePrice, secondaryBasePrice,
   >   tertiaryBasePrice values to do the compute?

. Yes, you are right, you need to send them as constructor parameters.

2. > Otherwise, why pass in the constructor order instance reference? Why
   >   is needed?

You need to pass the order instance reference in order to be able to call other methods of Order. In the example you gave, it is a trivial method, but in some other methods you might be calling some of the Order's methods...

One problem with this refactoring technique is that if your original method accesses Order's private methods, then you'd have to either make them package protected or replicate those methods in the target Method Object...

And if you make those private methods as package protected, then you get tight coupling, feature envy and maybe other problems